# Help with strangeness in Firefox (OSX only)

Tags: html, css, macos, firefox

I don't have a good way to test what's happening in the Poll area on this page in Firefox on OSX - hoping someone here could help. :)

Look in the left column, gray box "Vote on a video topic" area: http://rackertalent.com/videos/

From screenshots, this looks like maybe that one label is being given scrollbars (?). I've tried setting overflow: auto, hidden, etc and none of that worked. Any ideas on what this is and what's causing it?

Again, this only happens in Firefox / OS X. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep a scrollbar is appearing on the li "What is training like at Rackspace?". Adding overflow:hidden to this line fixed it for me in FF3.6 and FF6.0.2 on Mac:

```
.wp-polls ul li, .wp-polls-ul li, .wp-polls-ans ul li{overflow:hidden}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! Worked perfectly.